# corrupt data in decode base64 to image in Qt

Tags: qt, base64

I write a program decode the base64 string to image. I wrote a sample:

```
    QFile file("./image.jpg");

    if(!file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly | QIODevice::Text))
    {
        return;
    }

    QByteArray raw = file.readAll().toBase64();

    QImage = image;

    image.loadFromData(QByteArray::fromBase64(raw), "JPG");

    image.save("output.jpg", "JPG");
```

The output of the program is:

`Corrupt JPEG data: 65 extraneous bytes before marker 0xc0
Quantization table 0x01 was not defined`

I can't find something useful with google. I only read image file, and encode it with base64, then decode it. Could you tell me what's wrong with my code?

Comment: Sorry, I figure out what's wrong with my code. When i open the image file, i use the `QIODevice::Text` open mode. After i remove it the code run well.

Comment: Add your solution as an answer and select it as the answer. This is allowed, recommended even, and it might help someone else with a similar problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have figured out what's wrong with my code. When i open a image file, i use the `QIODevice::Text` open mode. But the image is a binary file, so i should remove the `QIODevice::Text` option. After do that, the code run well.

Comment: thank you so much for leaving behind this answer. when you solved your issue you didn't have to, but this just resolved hours and hours of debugging. thank you